# Angular 4: Change Detection between component and service

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-changedetection

I am currently working on a small test project with `Ionic/Angular`,
Before I post the snippets: the problem I have is that I want to send value changes from inside a service `(@Injectable)` to a `component` to track it's changes. I have tried EventEmitter and OnChanges, but to no avail..

I have a progressbar that needs a certain value to advance in progress. This is the progressbar:
**TS:**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'progressbar',
  templateUrl: 'progressbar.html'
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {

  @Input('progress') progress;

  constructor() {}
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner" [style.width]="progress + '%'">
        {‌{progress}}%
    </div>
</div>
```

(credit to JoshMorony)
The bar's width attribute is connected to the progress, thus enabling it to advance e.g. by percentage.

Now comes the problem:

I injected the progressbar into a normal component, but the calculation for the advancement happens in a different service, an Injectable. I am only able to send a single value, but not the advancement of the calculation and as such the bar itself:

**home.ts**

```
showProgressBar: boolean;
// this variable must always have a value between 0 - 100
loadProgress;

triggerEvent(){
this.service.showProgressbar = true;
}
```

**home.html**

```
<progressbar [progress]="loadProgress"></progressbar>
```

What is done here is simply a call to trigger an event, that includes the logic for that progressBar. By setting service'sshowProgressbar to true, I am indirectly setting the pages showprogressbar to true as well.

Note: the boolean is not used yet

Service looks like this:

```
denominator: number = 0;
counter: number = 0;
showProgressbar = false;

result: number = 0;
calculateProgress() {
  if (this.showProgressbar = true) {
    let percentage = Math.round((this.counter / this.denominator) * 100);
    this.result = percentage;
    if (this.result == 100) {
      setTimeout(this.showProgressbar = false, 500);
    }
  } else {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.denominator = 0;
    this.result = 0;
  }
}
```

I checked the calls, result here DOES calculate correctly, but it does not transfer to home.ts unfortunately. If I statically change result to a random number like 50 or so, it will indeed change the bar.

How can I make `home.ts` "watch" the value of result constantly or in another way how do I implement the change detection for that result value here?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Observable of the service and subscribe in home.ts

Your service

```
//create a Subject
private percentSource:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>();
//create a Observable
percentEvent:Observable<any>=this.percentSource.asObservable();
...
calculateProgress() {
  if (this.showProgressbar = true) {
    ...
    //send a change of observable with next
    this.percentSource.next(percentage);  //return as result the percent
    ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
}
```

then, in your home you can subscribe to the observable in the function tiggerEven or in progressBar.component in the ngOnInit function

```
triggerEvent(){
    this.service.showProgressbar = true;
    //takeWhile make you unsubscribe if condition is not successfully
    //NOT put if you subscribe in your progressBar.component
    this.service.percentEvent
    .takeWhile(() =>this.progress!=100)
    .subscribe(result=>  
    {
         this.progress=result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never used Observables but diving into it right now :-)